# I don't understand the Quotient Space well

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking examples of problems a their solutions that involved Quotient Spaces and someone commented the following:

... Let be $V=\Bbb R[x]$ and if $U=\{\text{polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(0)=0$}\}$, then $\dim(V/U)=1$...

Why the dimesion of $\dim(V/U)=1$?

Can someone explain, please.

Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[x]/U = \mathbb{R}[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is a 1-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The linear map $P\to P(0)$ from $V$ to $\bf R$ is surjective and its kernel is precisely $U$. So $\bf R$ is the quotient of $V$ by $U$, more precisely, the map $V\to \bf R$ $P\to P(0))$ induces an isomorphism  of $V/U$ with $\bf R$.

Comment: What do you know about quotient spaces? And ideals? If those are new concepts to you, it may be difficult to explain what's going on there. Very roughly speaking, $V$ is the set of polynomials in $x$ with real coefficients, and $U$ is the subset of $V$ restricted by the condition that the constant coefficient is $0$. (For instance, $x^2+2x-3$ is in $V$ but not $U$, while $x^3-\sqrt2x$ is in both $U$ and $V$.) In a sense, $V$ is the union of a set of "copies" of $U$, shifted up and down by an arbitrary amount. That amount can be indexed by the real axis, so the quotient space has dimension one.

Comment: Assuming that we're taking $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as the ring of polynomials in $x$, that is.

Answer (score 2):

To find the dimension of $\mathbb R[x]/U$, we must find a basis for it. This is actually pretty easy to do in this particular case just by starting with the standard basis for $\mathbb R[x]$:
$$
\{1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots\}
$$
Of these basis vectors, nearly all of them are in $U$. For instance, $0^2 = 0$, and therefore $x^2 \in U$ by definition of $U$. So, other than $1$, all of these basis vectors become zero in the quotient $\mathbb R[x]/U$. As a consequence, $\overline 1$ (the image of $1$ in the quotient space) spans all of $\mathbb R[x]/U$. So $\dim(\mathbb R[x]/U)$ is at most $1$.

The possibilities, then, are that $\dim(\mathbb R[x]/U)$ is $0$ or $1$. It is $0$ precisely when $\mathbb R[x]/U = \{\overline 0\}$. This is equivalent to $\mathbb R[x] = U$. But of course this is not true! For instance, $1 \notin U$, so $\mathbb R[x] \neq U$. So we conclude that the dimension is exactly $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of polynomials $p$ such that $p(0)=0$ are all of the polynomials whose constant term is $0$, i.e. $U=\{p: p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x\}$. A general polynomial of the form $q(x)=b_mx^m+...b_1x+b_0$ gets mapped to $U+b_0$ where $b_0\in\mathbb R$.

Therefore, the set of cosets in the quotient space is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and the dimension of the quotient space is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct. I will however propose another point of view. Consider the linear map:
$$
\mathrm{ev}_0:\left\{
\begin{matrix}
V & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R\\
p & \longmapsto & p(0).
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Note that this linear map is surjective and you can identify its kernel to be exactly $U$ (it is actually the definition of $U$ to be the kernel of this linear map). This gives the isomorphism of linear spaces:
$$
V/U\simeq \mathbb R.
$$
Thus, of course $\mathrm{dim}(V/U)=1$.